# Firebase Oauth disallowed user agent on third party app's web view

Tags: authentication, firebase, webview, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I am having trouble with OAuth authentication. The thing is the OAuth authentication works properly on normal browser, but it doesn't work on third party app's web view such as LINE or Facebook's Messenger. What happen is on third party app's web view, when user click "sign in with google", for instant, Google will show error page 403 error: "disallowed_useragent". (This happens when I try to send the link to my web application to my friend via the Messenger. When my friend click on the link, Messenger open my web application on their web view. My friend won't be able to click sign in then)

Therefore, I do some searches and found out that Google has deprecated OAuth authentication via the web view. Here is the [LINK](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html).

So my questions is:
    Is it possible to force user to open normal browser if web view is detected?
    Or are there some ways to work around with this?

I am using Firebase authentication for this. All of my codes use Firebase SDK for authentication firebase-auth.js and firebase.js)

Comment: Hi,

I'm struggling with the same issue.
I'm afraid that the only solution lays on Facebook themselves.
They only have the option to use what google suggest:

Modern “in-app browser tab” patterns available on some operating systems, such as Chrome Custom Tabs on Android and SFSafariViewController on iOS offer further UX improvements for browser-based OAuth flows.

I hope someone will find a creative solution for this.

Comment: @shgutman yea, I think I am on the dead-end on this. :( sad..

Answer (score 0):

Google restricts the authentication from webviews and iframes,it allowes safari webkit.if you override user agent with safari user agent then it will works.
 try this once it will works

```
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
```

Comment: Can you please add more description regarding your answer.

Comment: Misleading user agent is against firebase policy for authentication :( ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you try **Google API Setting?**
If you want to use Google Login, you need setting for OAuth in Google API Console.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect

[image]